# Advice about spring transaction management redesign

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I will try to describe the issue I'm trying to solve. I realized that an app that I've developed has a poorly implemented spring transaction management. I'm using declarative approach with transactions defined on DAO interface methods (CRUD), not on service layer methods. It's a web app that does some kind of message processing and multiple threads operate on the same message instance simultaneously. Here are the steps in a typical sequence:

1. Message is created in T1 (transaction 1) and is put into outbound queue. T1 is terminated.
2. Message is taken from the queue by a different thread, sent and updated with time of sending and some additional info. Properties of the message object are set and dao.update(m) is called, t2 starts.
3. Before t2 commits, delivery report is received and Tread3 starts to process same message object by finding it in db (saved in step 1), updating it's state property and calling dao.upate(m) so t3 starts while t2 is still in progress.
4. Another thread (thread 4) further process same message object by changing it's state again in t4.

The result that occurs from time to time is that changes from t2 are lost and sending time is null in db. 
I need help in figuring out how to improve app design and eliminate this issue by preventing concurrent processing of the same message.

1. Should I concentrate on transaction redesign (using it on service level instead of dao) and using the serializable isolation level(or other) or
2. should i use JPA entity manager locking?

App uses spring 3 and JPA2 with hibernate implementation.

Comment: How is the message sent? JMS? Web service? Other? Could you make this part of a global distributed transaction (in case of JMS)? If not, shouldn't you simply send the message after T2 has finished, and thus be sure that T2 has ended when the delivery report is received?

Comment: Messages are sent via third party web service. T2 could not execute before message is sent 'cause messages are updated with sending result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd move the transactions to the service level, but I'd rethink the whole design, and see if you can get the whole process into one thread. If I remember correctly, Spring's transaction management is thread-based - I doubt that you're going to be able to have a transaction that spans threads.

Also, try to simplify things, if possible, so that you hit the database only once.
If you really need four separate updates, run them sequentially in the same transaction in the same thread. Otherwise, you're not going to have a good time trying to get a transaction to work.

Explicit locking is also asking for a world of hurt - you're very likely to wind up with deadlocks doing that.

Edit: In response to OP's comment:

I suggest finding a way to separate the T3 update from the T2 update, and let the T2 transaction commit before doing the T3 update.

Perhaps put the delivery report on a message queue. 
Then come up with a strategy for finding the item in T3 and doing the update if it exists, or trying again later if it does not.

If you know that there is a minimum or average amount of time between receipt of the delivery report and the end of the T2 transaction, perhaps you could build that amount of delay into processing of the delivery receipt to create the T3 update.

Comment: Unfortunately, i cant avoid multiple threads because delivery reports are received via HTTP. I did some researching on the topic of transaction isolation, and it seams that RDMS is responsible for transaction handling not spring. But i wonder what will happen if I set serializable isolation for T2 and T3? T2 will acquire lock on the table and when t3 tries to do the same, will it wait for lock to release or will fail and throw an exception?